# MSSQL logon trigger blocks nodejs connections

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am getting a logon trigger execution error when connecting through nodejs (I am using the npm package mssql), but not when connecting through a client or python.

Is there a way to hide that I'm connecting through node?

Comment: The real answer is, if you need to login via node, then change the trigger. This is an XY problem. Post the DDL of the Login trigger, and we can help you find out why you can't use Node and how to change the trigger so that you can.

Comment: I don't have the ability to change the trigger.

Comment: Then the trigger is likely working as intended, especially if you can't change it. Stop trying to get around the security settings at your work place. If you do need to, you need to speak to your DBA, not members of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not a DBA, which is why I said I didn't have the ability to change the trigger. This is not a security setting at our workplace. it's an external database we have access to. I don't see why they would block node but not python, or if the mssql package was sending something thats not handled by this sql (they said it was mini sql and we don't know if that needs to receive specific settings). Can you flag my question if it shouldn't be here, would like to get an official response from stackoverflow admin so I can make sure I'm following the rules (or link the rule that says i shouldn't ask).

Comment: My point is that we can't help you here; you have a trigger that you're trying to get around, that you don't know the definition of, and that you don't have access to change. There isn't anything we can do to get you to connect and you're clearly being denied for a reason. You need to speak to whomever is in charge of the SQL Server you are trying to connect to. Admins on SO don't get involved with telling you things like that.

Comment: Okay, so it is possible to block node? I wasn't sure if a trigger could even do something like that, and didn't know if they would even know what I was talking about if it wasn't. I'll ask them, but I don't think they are denying us for a reason if we could access through python. Apologies I misunderstood when you said I shouldn't ask members on stack overflow about this question. you were saying no one could help me. thanks for that.